# Yarn-Cluster mode - ApplicationMaster: SparkContext did not initialize after waiting for 100000 ms

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

in my pyspark program i have as,

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext, SQLContex  
conf=SparkConf()  
conf.setAppName("spark_name")  
conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")  
conf.set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true")  
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

And running my pyspark program as

```
./spark-submit --master yarn-cluster PySparkProgramPath
```

then this job failed with

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1482268372614_0318 finished with failed status
```

after i run `yarn logs -applicationId application_1482268372614_0318`
it showing the error

```
ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
ERROR ApplicationMaster: SparkContext did not initialize after waiting for 100000 ms. Please check earlier log output for errors.
```

[EDIT] Not facing this error when i submit this in `yarn-client` mode

Comment: I believe it should be --master yarn, not yarn-cluster, see  http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html
It may be trying to access master on 'yarn-cluster' host

Comment: @DenisMakarenko, `--master yarn-cluster` means master is yarn and deploy mode is cluster. Getting the same error even if i mention both separately.